# Create Html template document from Javascript and Php variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am developping an application. As final result the application generates a Html document consisting of variables from external Javascript and Php files.Which is the safest way to pass these variables?.

Thank you very much.

Comment: post what code you have tried?

Comment: To pass variable from php you can use GET or POST method. GET method has limitation besides it is not safer than POST.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The code inside Html that i have used is `    
<script>
    var variablejs = "javascript variable content" ;
</script>
<?php
$variablephp = "<script> document.write(variablejs) </script>";
echo "variablephp = $variablephp";
?>`but it doesn't work.

I will try to work with POST method.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX to do this, you make the request in JS, and process the information in PHP(server side), and you can return an JSON Object with the variables, or simply, return the HTML code and output it.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: So the security on variables comes from Ajax code or Php?.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you should add your security In PHP.